# I am trying to insert data into a table through procedure but an error occur i.e.' ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object'

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_insert (p_emp_id        IN munber,
                              p_emp_ename     IN VARCHAR2,
                              p_emp_job       IN VARCHAR2,
                              p_emp_dept      IN NUMBER,
                              p_emp_hiredate  IN DATE,
                              p_emp_loc       IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO emp
        VALUES (p_emp_id,
                p_emp_ename,
                p_emp_job,
                p_emp_dept,
                p_emp_hiredate,
                p_emp_loc);
END;

EXECUTE proc_insert(33,'rohit','web developer',10,'12-apr-2020','kanpur');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the insert that's causing problem, but the fact that object named `proc_insert` already exists in this schema.

Find out which one is it and - if you don't need it - drop it. How? Query `user_objects`.

Or, maybe you actually wanted to use

```
create OR REPLACE procedure proc_insert ...
       ----------
```

which would do the job.

---

As of code you posted: note that `p_emp_hiredate`'s datatype is `date`, while you're passing a **string** to it. `'12-apr-2020'` is a string, not a date. You'd rather not rely on current NLS settings and Oracle's implicit datatype conversion - pass date, e.g.

- a date literal: `date '2022-04-12'`
- or use `to_date` function: `to_date('12-apr-2020', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')`

---

To illustrate it:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_insert (p_emp_id        IN NUMBER,
  2                                           p_emp_ename     IN VARCHAR2,
  3                                           p_emp_job       IN VARCHAR2,
  4                                           p_emp_dept      IN NUMBER,
  5                                           p_emp_hiredate  IN DATE,
  6                                           p_emp_loc       IN VARCHAR2)
  7  IS
  8  BEGIN
  9     INSERT INTO temp
 10          VALUES (p_emp_id,
 11                  p_emp_ename,
 12                  p_emp_job,
 13                  p_emp_dept,
 14                  p_emp_hiredate,
 15                  p_emp_loc);
 16  END;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXECUTE proc_insert(33,'rohit','web developer',10,date '2020-04-12','kanpur');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM temp;

        ID ENAME      JOB                   DEPT HIREDATE   LOC
---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        33 rohit      web developer           10 12.04.2020 kanpur

SQL>
```

Comment: I already drop the procedure but enable to execute

Comment: Which error did you get? Have a look at edited answer which shows that it *works* for me. Also, note that the first parameter's datatype in your code is wrong; it is not "munber" but "number".